# Ajax response won't return data

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-3

I can't find why my ajax won't return any data. if i used print_r($data), my results will be shown but if i just returned $data it won't show the results, my code as follows. (Im using codeigniter)

```
$.ajax({   
            method :'GET',
            url:baseUrl+'page/getToken/'+getUrlParameter('code'),
          dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
                alert(data); 
            },
            complete: function(){

            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){alert(thrownError);}
            });
```

Page Controller

```
public function getToken($CODE)
{
    return $this->EnvatoOperationsHandler->get_envato_token($CODE);
}
```

Model EnvatoOperationsHandler

```
function get_envato_token($code) {

    $api_url = 'https://api.envato.com/';
    $EnvatoSettings['envatoapi']=$this->get_data();
    $client_id = $EnvatoSettings['envatoapi'][0]['e_clientID'];
    $client_secrets_envo = $EnvatoSettings['envatoapi'][0]['e_clientSecret'];


    $redirect_uri='http://localhost/verify/settings';
    $client_secret=$client_secrets_envo;
    //private $access_token;
    //private $personal_token;

    $url = $api_url.'token';
    $params = array(
        'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
        'code'          => $code,
        'redirect_uri'  => $redirect_uri,
        'client_id'     => $client_id,
        'client_secret' => $client_secret,
    );
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $data = json_decode($result, true);
    //print_r($data);
    exit(json_encode($data));
}
```

Comment: Change your return to: exit($data).

Comment: just tried and it gives me an error "array to string conversion"

Comment: My apologies. Try "exit(json_encode($data))". And then add "dataType: 'json'" to your ajax object.

Comment: it displays "[object Object]" in my alert , is there anyway that i can access my array within the ajax response?

Answer (score 0):

Beans answer was correct . so i have modified the above code according to his answer and it worked. Thanks.